# Телеграм бот отвечающий за погоду падает после неправильного введение города

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, pyowm

Телеграм бот отвечающий за погоду падает после неправильного введение города. Что нужно написать чтобы он не падал а отвечал что город введен неправильно?
Вот такая ошибка выходит:

```
ERROR - TeleBot: "NotFoundError occurred, args=('Unable to find the resource',)
```

вот сам код:

```
import pyowm
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'
owm = OWM('489f45987eb92460dc4955babb3bbeec', config_dict)

import telebot

owm = pyowm.OWM('489f45987eb92460dc4955babb3bbeec')
mgr =  owm.weather_manager()

bot = telebot.TeleBot("1317148098:AAFoaJ5MVh-Q6Y2c2fCpRL496CbivpersAg")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    observation =  mgr.weather_at_place( message.text )
    w =  observation.weather
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]

    answer = f"В городе {message.text} сейчас {w.detailed_status}\n"
    answer += " Температура сейчас примерно градусов "+ str(temp) + "\n\n"

    if temp < 10:
        answer += "Сейчас жестко холодно, куртку одевай ежже" 
    elif temp < 20:
        answer += "Сейчас прохладно, оденься потеплее" 
    else:
        answer += "Температура найс, одевайся как хош" 

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
bot.polling( none_stop = True)
```

Comment: Нужно завернуть тело функции `send_echo` в try except и предпринимать необходимые действия в блоке except.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Comment: Можно еще Rasa или аналог подключить, это прям многие траблы порешает )

Answer (score 1):

добавь это в функцию:

```
try: 
    observation =  mgr.weather_at_place( message.text )
    w =  observation.weather
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]
except NotFoundError:
    answer = "город не найден!"
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Ваш бот ловит исключение **NotFoundError** при введении *неправильного* либо *несуществующего* города, поэтому Вам можно попробывать конструкцию с `try` и `except` для ловли подобного рода проблем, как у пользователя давшего ответ ниже.

Также можно добавить конструкцию с `while` которая будет спрашивать у пользователя повторное введение города, до того момента, пока город не будет верный. К примеру:

```
while True:
      try:
          observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
          w = observation.weather
          temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]
          break
          # Если всё верно и исключение не возникает, цикл завершается и продолжается работа.
      except NotFoundError:
          # Запрос на введение города.
```