# Как сделать, чтобы бот не слетал при неверном значении на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, pip

Создаю погодного бота телеграм на питоне, при неверном значении он слетает, как сделать, чтобы при неверном значении бот выдавал ошибку?

Comment: try/catch? ....

Comment: Ответ [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1181782/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)